# Laravel / MySQL / Eloquent: Grouped Clauses

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a search function on my website whereby a user can search by different properties of cars in certain ranges. The user may or may not choose to search by a certain property. These arrays are just dynamic and can have 0, 1, 2, or 3 entries, depending on what the use selected (so the query must be dynamic) i.e.:

```
$price_ranges = [
  [0, 1000],
  [1000, 2000],
  [2000, 3000]
];

$weight_ranges = [
  [1000, 2000],
  [5000, 9999]
]
```

I want to use the querybuilder in Laravel/Eloquent to construct an appropriate query for this but I'm having a lot of difficulty grouping the clauses. This is what I have:

```
$query = Shipment::with(['cars']);

foreach($price_ranges as $price_range){
  $query->whereHas('cars', function($q) use(&$price_range){
    $q->where('price', '>=', $range[0])->where('price', '<=', $range[1]);
  });
}

foreach($weight_ranges as $weight_range){
  $query->whereHas('cars', function($q) use(&$weight_range){
    $q->where('weight', '>=', $range[0])->where('weight', '<=', $range[1]);
  });
}

$results = $query->get();
```

The problem with this code is that it's finding shipments that have cars which satisfy **each** of the price conditions... but I want it to find shipments where it satisfies **any** of the conditions and return only the relevant cars. I've created a schematic to better illustrate what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: It may help if you specify which is the actual SQL statement that you would like to run, so help can be provided con building the correct eloquent call to achieve the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to user orWhereHas instead or whereHas! but you need to wrap the whole weight query with one where

```
$query = Shipment::with(['cars']);

foreach($price_ranges as $price_range){
  $query->orWhereHas('cars', function($q) use(&$price_range){
    $q->where('price', '>=', $range[0])->where('price', '<=', $range[1]);
  });
}

foreach($weight_ranges as $weight_range){
  $query->where(function($q) use(..) {
    $q->orWhereHas('cars', function($q) use(&$weight_range){
        $q->where('weight', '>=', $range[0])->where('weight', '<=', $range[1]);
    });
  });
}

$results = $query->get();
```

I might be completely wrong, haven't done this in a long time. Please let me know and good luck.